# When is kill-emacs-hook called?

Tags: emacs, elisp, kill

If I have some unsaved buffers, when does `kill-emacs-hook` call?

Scenario A

1. User invoke `kill-emacs`.
2. Prompt for saving modified buffers.
3. Cancel `kill-emacs` operation (`C-g`).
4. User continues to use emacs.

Scenario B

1. User invoke `kill-emacs`.
2. Prompt for saving modified buffers.
3. All modified buffers saved
4. Emacs killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `kill-emacs-hook` is the first thing which `kill-emacs` does.

Both of your scenarios are invalid. If the user directly invokes `kill-emacs` the user is *not* prompted to save buffers (that's only done if `save-buffers-kill-emacs` is called).

For the latter, if the user aborts the query to save buffers, or if any of the members of `kill-emacs-query-functions` return `nil`, then `kill-emacs` is never called.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I finally `advice-add` `:before` the `save-buffers-kill-emacs` to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this line of code and exited emacs to test what was happening.

`(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook (lambda () (message "test")))`

The conclusion was that "test was" not printed in `Scenario A` but was printed in `Scenario B` between steps `3.` and `4.`

There were a few more lines of output after the printing of "text" in example B but there was no more user input.

Comment: Em.... I did try this. But there is a problem that 3 and 4 runs almost at the same time so I can never see the message log.